# Read attachments data from email using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm attempting to use code to read an email and its attachments. I can read the email using Python's extract msg module, but not the attachment content. I am printing the attachments variable but its showing list object and not the content. The code for this is provided below. Please share your thoughts on this.

```
import extract_msg
import glob
import re
f = glob.glob('Time Off -DAYS.msg')


for filename in f:
    msg = extract_msg.Message(filename)
    
    msg_from = msg.sender
    msg_date = msg.date
    msg_subj = msg.subject
    msg_message = msg.body
    attachments = msg.attachments
    msg_to = msg.to
print("To:-",msg_to)
print("From:-",msg_from)
print ("Date:-",msg.date)
print(attachments)
```

attachments data: Email has 2 attachments
[<extract_msg.attachment.Attachment object at 0x0000024444C9FEF0>, <extract_msg.attachment.Attachment object at 0x0000024444E39C50>]

Answer (score 0):

you use multiple libraries to reading Email Data 
smtplib , imaplib, pywin32 
I use pywin32 here and use Outlook 
to reading and downloading Emails and Attachments: 
first, you have to install and import the module:

```
pip install pywin32
import win32com.client
```

second Establish a Connection:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

third Read the Email:

```
# Access to the email in the inbox
messages = inbox.Items
# get the first email
message = messages.GetFirst()
# get the last email
#message = messages.GetLast()
# to loop thru the email in the inbox 
while True:
  try:
    print(message.subject) # get the subject of the email
    # if you use messages.GetFirst() earlier
    message = messages.GetNext() 
    # if you use messages.GetPrevious() earlier 
    #message = messages.GetPrevious()
  except:
    # if you use messages.GetFirst() earlier
    message = messages.GetNext() 
    # if you use messages.GetPrevious() earlier 
    #message = messages.GetPrevious()
```

The above example shows how to print the subject of all of the emails in the Inbox.

Below are some of the common properties:

```
message.subject
message.senton               # return the date & time email sent
message.senton.date()
message.senton.time()
message.sender
message.SenderEmailAddress
message.Attachments          # return all attachments in the email
```

Download and Email Attachment:

```
attachments = message.Attachments
# return the first item in attachments
attachment = attachments.Item(1)
# the name of attachment file      
attachment_name = str(attachment).lower()
attachment.SaveASFile(path+ '\\' + attachment_name)
```

I hope that works fine for you
for more information check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/automatic-download-email-attachment-with-python-4aa59bc66c25) link and [this](https://medium.com/@sdoshi579/to-read-emails-and-download-attachments-in-python-6d7d6b60269) link

Comment: Thanks for the answer @seyed amirreza kabodian , I don't want to connect to outlook. I will be getting specific email copied into some path n for ther I will be reading the mail

Comment: what are you content of your attachments? some data types and objects cannot print directly to the console...

Comment: attachments have pdf files and its data we need to print and search some keywords

Comment: this is obvious you cannot read/and print pdf files directly with python. you have to save that file and then read a file with pdf packages and then do your work..., for saving file attachments you can see two links that I have given above.